# SQL Join query ; Order vs Invoice

Tags: sql, join, derby

I'm bit new in writing SQL join queries and I need a help with join quires. Here is the table.

```
Table : Txn
TXN_KEY     TYPE      DATE
--------------------------
111          OD       10/5   
221          CS       11/5 
112          OD       12/5
222          CS       12/5

Table: TxnAssociation
TXN_KEY      REF_TXN_KEY     TYPE
---------------------------------
221           111             OS
```

Type `OD` is order and `CS` is customer sale. There are certain open orders and there are some sale without orders.

Need a join query to get output like

```
ORD      SAL
--------------
111      221
112      null
null     222
```

I'm using derby. I'd tried something but it is not worth to debug. Can any one help please...

Comment: Please explain in detail how you came to the desired result set. How is 111 connected to 221? Why not 112 to 222?

Comment: @fancyPants see the table `TxnAssociation` there is a association b/w 111 and 221 but 112 and 222 dont have that.

Comment: Oh, yes, missed that somehow :)

Comment: Dear down voters please put the reason in comment for down voting.

Answer (score 1):

ok, this one is without full join

```
  SELECT orders.TXN_KEY as ORD,ta.TXN_KEY as SAL
    FROM Txn orders 
    LEFT JOIN TxnAssociation ta ON orders.TXN_KEY = ta.REF_TXN_KEY 
   WHERE isnull(orders.Type,'OD') = 'OD'
UNION ALL 
  SELECT NULL  as ORD,sales.TXN_KEY as SAL
    FROM Txn sales
   WHERE sales.Type= 'CS'
 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM Txn s 
                   JOIN TxnAssociation t ON s.TXN_KEY = t.TXN_KEY 
                                            AND s.Type= 'CS' AND sales.TXN_KEY = s.TXN_KEY)
```

and this one is better:

```
SELECT orders.TXN_KEY as ORD,ta.TXN_KEY as SAL
  FROM Txn orders 
  LEFT JOIN TxnAssociation ta ON orders.TXN_KEY = ta.REF_TXN_KEY 
 WHERE isnull(orders.Type,'OD') = 'OD'
UNION ALL 
SELECT ta.REF_TXN_KEY  as ORD,sales.TXN_KEY as SAL
 FROM Txn sales
 LEFT JOIN TxnAssociation ta ON sales.TXN_KEY = ta.TXN_KEY
WHERE sales.Type= 'CS'
  AND ta.REF_TXN_KEY is null
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   SELECT orders.TXN_KEY as ORD, sales.TXN_KEY as SAL
     FROM TxnAssociation ta
     FULL JOIN Txn orders ON orders.TXN_KEY = ta.REF_TXN_KEY 
     FULL JOIN Txn sales ON sales.TXN_KEY = ta.TXN_KEY 
    WHERE isnull(orders.Type,'OD') = 'OD'
      AND isnull(sales.Type,'CS') = 'CS'
```

Comment: sorry, I can not try since full join type not available in derby https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.5/ref/rrefsqlj29840.html

Comment: But Derby has both LEFT OUTER JOIN and RIGHT OUTER JOIN, so you can UNION them.